# detailTextLabel doesn't show

Tags: ios, swift

i have a function in which i want a big text label and two smaller text label. 
The function takes data from a database, and puts them repeatingly into my 3 textlabels. 
However, only my default textlabel is visible, Both detailTextLabels doesn't show.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Retrieve cell
    let cellIdentifier: String = "BasicCell"
    let myCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)!
    // Get the location to be shown
    let item: Parsexml = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! Parsexml
    // Get references to labels of cell
    print(item)
    myCell.textLabel!.text = item.name! + " | " + item.address! + " " + item.nr!
    myCell.detailTextLabel?.text = "City: " + item.city!
    myCell.detailTextLabel?.text = "category: " + item.category!
    //Label styling
    myCell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 1)
    myCell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 12)
    return myCell
}
```

How do i get my detail text labels to show in swift 3?

Comment: Maybe you forgot `.addSubview` in your cell?

Comment: Since your cell seems like being custom cell you need to create a custom class to refer this cell (by subclassing `UITableViewCell` of-course). Then use that class, access your custom cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means you have custom cell which has 3 UILables?
if so this line should be like this

```
 let myCell: YouCustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)!
```

Then you can use

```
myCell.1stLable.text = item.name! + " | " + item.address! + " " + item.nr!
myCell.2ndLable.text = "City: " + item.city!
myCell.3rdLable.text = "category: " + item.category!
```

You must set the cell identifier in storyboard.

Comment: I don't get it. My storyboard identifier is called "BasicCell" 
- And the style is set to custom? 

So what is it exactly this does? I should be able to at least put a detailTextLabel within this?

Comment: You have to create a subclass of UITableViewCell and drag those UILables to that class and make outlet of them

Comment: Can i do that when my content is repeating??